Creating a Python virtual environment with the same specifications as Google colab
I'm having issues installing a custom package using Python. I've tried several different laptops, including some of friends, but it doesn't work. For some reason on Google colab it works absolutely fine and I can end up using the package. However, for my purposes I need it to also run locally. How can I recreate the colab environment locally, on say VSCode?
